# React.js mobile site freezes in Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

We have a problem with a React.js site acting up, specifically on Chrome/Android. Haven't been able to replicate it in other browsers or platforms (desktop is always smooth).

It is seemingly related to the front page, most likely the amount of images being loaded. For some reason, other browsers (even Chrome on iOS) do not seem to struggle with it.

I have not been able to recreate it with a simple example, but a working, live example can be found at our dev site https://beta.fotmob.com, where you can see that it freezes after a couple of random clicks (using Chrome on Android). The site is server rendered, and all components are React components except a Facebook ad at the top (React component with dangerouslySetInnerHTML for the FB ad code).

There's also another, strange issue regarding any kind of overlay (search button at the bottom or calendar at the top, specifically): Closing the search or selecting a date is a touchend event, which seems to "stick", and will then trigger the hyperlink beneath (match or league), despite the meta tag: 
*meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width"*

The clicks aren't going "through"; they are definitely appearing after the overlay has been removed, but the 300ms delay shouldn't be present anymore. At any rate, I do not believe this to be the cause of the freezes, but I figured it might be worth mentioning.

Any thoughts or ideas as to what may be causing the problems, or why it's browser specific?

Edit: 
Just adding the solution here, for people who don't want to keep reading.

Freeze issue: Caused by a number of setTimeout calls that modified the state after the page was loaded. Why it would cause issues specifically in Chrome on Android is still a mystery, however. Perhaps Chrome on Android deals with either state changes or a high number of JS calls differently.

Double click issue: This appears to be a bug either in React or Chrome. Basically, the hyperlink was being triggered after the 0,3ms delay regardless of meta tag, but the onClick was not. So onClick is working as intended. The work-around is to simply move the actual navigation from href to onClick.

Comment: For the touch events, maybe your event handlers just need a `stopPropagation()`? And for both the freezing and the touch issues, I'd run a JS CPU profile in DevTools to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve both issues.

Freeze issue: Caused by a number of setTimeout calls that modified the state after the page was loaded. Why it would cause issues specifically in Chrome on Android is still a mystery, however. Perhaps Chrome on Android deals with either state changes or a high number of JS calls differently.

Double click issue: This appears to be a bug either in React or Chrome. Basically, the hyperlink was being triggered after the 0,3ms delay regardless of meta tag, but the onClick was not. So onClick is working as intended. The work-around is to simply move the actual navigation from href to onClick.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where I have setInterval calls and the entire page freezes after some hours/days. How did you solve the timeout issue?

Comment: I wish I could help, but this is almost five years ago, so I don't remember the exact details.   I seem to recall spending some time reducing the overall complexity and number of state changes, but I can't remember the specifics. Sorry about that.